# WebPart Charts - Data Not Appearing

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part

I have created a WebPart Chart extracting data from a list. Within the list there is a calucated field, that when the chart is generated it will show fields for year and month in order.

Formula used:

```
=YEAR([Date Inspected])
 &"-"
 &CHOOSE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MONTH([Date Inspected])
                         &"/"
                         &YEAR([Date Inspected])
                        )
              )
        ,"01. January"
        ,"02. February"
        ,"03. March"
        ,"04. April"
        ,"05. May"
        ,"06. June"
        ,"07. July"
        ,"08. August"
        ,"09. September"
        ,"10. October"
        ,"11. November"
        ,"12. December"
        )
```

The first entry in the list was July 2014. So the field generates "2014-07. July". Now everything after June 2015 is not appearing on the chart.

Does anyone has suggestions on how to change the formula to get my data to appear or to change something within the WebPart ezEdit?

Answer (score 0):

First your Formula.

You can rewrite it to:

```
=TEXT([Date Inspected],"yyyy-mm. mmmm")
```

If you really want the capitalization of the month name:

```
=TEXT([Date Inspected],"yyyy-mm. ") & PROPER(TEXT([Date Inspected],"mmmm"))
```

Your sorting problem I do not quite understand.

Another trick that is often used in Grouping is to prepend the label with spaces (which are ignored in HTML) but force alfabethical sorting.

```
=REPT(MONTH([Date Inspected])," ")&TEXT([Date Inspected],"yyyy-mm. mmmm")
```

But I have no clue what you are doing (HTML wise) in that WebPart